# SDK to Encode and Decode JPEG2000 images from C++ code

Tags: jpeg2000

I am looking for an SDK for (roughly) the following capabilities regarding JPEG2000 files –

1. Decode and encode J2K files.
2. Decode to access individual elements (boxes, marker segments, image stream, etc.) of JPEG2000 images for inspection and potential alteration of texts and bits.
3. Encode (reconstruct) the JPEG2000 image with given elements.
4. This is all done from within C++ applications.
5. It must support 64-bit Redhat Linux OS.
6. It should be able to handle J2K (JPEG2000) files as large as 16GB i.e. 64-bit file address.

Please tell me of SDK's with the above capabilities that you know or have used in your projects. Also, hints on performance and licensing/pricing would be appreciated.

Comment: By "jpg2000", I assume you mean the file format used for digital projection in our local theaters (or something close).  Correct?  Have you looked at [OpenJPEG](http://www.openjpeg.org/)?

Comment: Hi Paulsm4, thanks for your response. Yes, I have looked into OpenJPEG and JasPer libraries (which are free). I am looking for other SDK's besides those two.

Comment: Wikipedia usually have a list of everything. Start the search from JPEG2000.

Answer (score 1):

The best JPEG 2000 library is Kakadu: http://www.kakadusoftware.com/

1. No problems, Kakadu can handle raw codestreams (j2c) and file formatted codestreams (jp2)
2. Full codestream access and manipulation.
3. Not sure what you mean here, but if you mean to assemble components together or pieces of an image (i.e. like tiles.) yes, Kakadu is more than capable.
4. Yes, it's written in C++ so it will easily integrate with other C++ applications.
5. Yes, every major platform is supported.
6. Yes, 64bit addressing is supported.

Source: http://www.kakadusoftware.com/documents/Overview.txt

As for pricing and licensing model, it's a bit different for how you use it. Licenses start from $250USD for individual licenses, $500USD for evaluation licenses. See here for the most accurate details on licensing: http://www.kakadusoftware.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=blogcategory&id=6&Itemid=12

Kakadu is authored by David Taubman, one of the key contributors to the JPEG 2000 specification. If you need JPEG 2000 to do something more, he will be a great person to ask for help.

Comment: $250USD is for NON commercial licenses. commercial licenses are a lot more expensive...

Answer (score 0):

Another commercial library to do this is Accusoft Pictools. 
We use it for Medical Imaging purposes. 
It supports most known formats including jpeg2000 (.jp2).

https://www.accusoft.com/pictools.htm

Has complete libraries to be called from unmanaged code.

regards

Ari